# Plastic wrap sticking to spine of Blu-Ray disc packages

Tags: cleaning, adhesive, plastics

One thing that drives me nuts about Blu-Rays is that for some reason the packaging methodology causes the outer cellophane-like wrap to stick to the spine of disc case, so when you take it off, there is a messy residue all along the spine which looks terrible, because the spine is the part you see when the case is sitting on a shelf.

To prove I am not making this up, there is [a discussion thread on this exact problem in a different forum](https://forum.dvdtalk.com/dvd-talk-covers-cases-inserts/566100-dvd-plastic-wrap-sticks-spine-case.html) with some proposed remedies which I have found not to work very well.

My questions are:

1. why is this happening?
2. how can I get the plastic residue off the spine of the case?

Comment: @BrettFromLA Since you have a ton of rep and activity there, I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Subscribing to an online movie streaming service might well relieve you of this burden. Might cost less too?! ;)

Comment: I wonder if this is region dependent - I have never seen this on any of my Blue-ray discs in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that glue is so much stronger but [Googone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IBNJ) will definitely remove it with minimal effort.

Comment: Which [Goo Gone](https://googone.com/) product do you refer to?

Comment: Just the original Goo Gone is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the residue is an adhesive (glue) Goo Gone is the answer to the problem. I've been using it for more than 20 years and it is the bomb for adhesive removal.

If the residue is is just the plastic wrapping sticking to the spine because of the shrink wrapping process or due to static electricity a little soap and water (Dawn dish-washing soap is great) almost always breaks the shrink wrap seal and eliminates the static charge by providing a path away from the wrapping and plastic case.  Might need a small brush, too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old Question, but WD-40 works well to remove the glue. Just a few drops, a little gentle scrubbing, and it should dissolve. Then a quick wipe down or wash with dish soap on the affected area, and it should be good as new.